# In R datatable, how to identify block of rows of variable length?

Tags: r, datatable

I have a large datatable with a 'status' column. Status could be 0, 1, or 2. Zero or more rows of status 0 or 2 can precede a row with status of 1. E.g.

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), status = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

I want to identify the groups 1 (id = 1), 2 (id = 2:3), 3 (id = 4:6), and 4 (id = 7:10).
Is there an efficient way to do this instead of running through a loop?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: what logic defines the grouping?

Comment: Any number of rows with status 0 or 2 can precede a row with status 1. There is no way to predict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), status = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
dt[,.(group=rleid(rev(cumsum(rev(status==1)))), id, status)]
#>     group id status
#>  1:     1  1      1
#>  2:     2  2      0
#>  3:     2  3      1
#>  4:     3  4      0
#>  5:     3  5      2
#>  6:     3  6      1
#>  7:     4  7      0
#>  8:     4  8      0
#>  9:     4  9      0
#> 10:     4 10      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: similar solution, though used `status>0`

Comment: Any reference for what would be `baseR` and `tidyverse` alternatives?

Comment: rleid in this case only reenumerates the groups. `group=rev(cumsum(rev(status==1)))` is base R . The `rleid` equivalent in base r is `with(rle(rev(cumsum(rev(status==1)))), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))` but you can also reenumerate in other ways, i.e. `match(group, unique(group))` or `max(group) - group + 1`